# How to Hot Deployment an Application on Open Shift

Tags: openshift

I have already made a web application which I want to deploy on Open shift .I have already cloned application git repository by using the following command ran on terminal as:-

```
 [root@mac1 Desktop]# git clone ssh://519dcdc44382ec1c9200002d@ntd-
 diagnostics.rhcloud.com/~/git/ntd.git/
 Initialized empty Git repository in /home/Ravi/Desktop/ntd/.git/
 The authenticity of host 'ntd-diagnostics.rhcloud.com (54.235.28.28)' can't be 
 established.
 RSA key fingerprint is cf:ee:77:cb:0e:fc:02:d7:72:7e:ae:80:c0:90:88:a7.
 Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
 Warning: Permanently added 'ntd-diagnostics.rhcloud.com,54.235.28.28' (RSA) to the list   
 of known hosts.
 remote: Counting objects: 41, done.
 remote: Compressing objects: 100% (34/34), done.
 remote: Total 41 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
 Receiving objects: 100% (41/41), 38.37 KiB, done.
 Resolving deltas: 100% (1/1), done.
```

Now I don't know the next steps. As I am guessing that I will have to deploy my project in clonned local directory which made after this command but  I don't know how will I do that

Answer (score 1):

Please either go through the entire documentation here: https://www.openshift.com/sites/default/files/documents/OpenShift-2.0-User_Guide-en-US_5.pdf

or go through "Getting Started" steps from here: 
https://www.openshift.com/get-started#cli